# sql loader transferring some characters into?

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I faced problems while importing data from .csv into Oracle database. I am using Oracle Sql Loader utility.
Characters which do not exist in the English alphabet were transformed to question marks in the target Oracle table.

Which settings should I modify?

Answer (score 1):

What data type are the columns you're loading the data into?  VARCHAR2?  NVARCHAR2?  Or something else?

What is your database and national character set?

```
SELECT *
  FROM v$nls_parameters
 WHERE parameter LIKE '%CHARACTERSET'
```

What character set is your flat file encoded in?  What character set, if any, did you specify in your SQL*Loader control file?